# Teria como abrir uma janela do cmd pelo php via web?

Tags: php, cmd

Estou utilizando o seguinte código abaixo:

```
$wShell = new COM("WScript.Shell"); 
$exec = $wShell->Run("notepad.exe", 7, false); 
 exec("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\boxlabel\box_bat.bat") or die ("");
```

Gostaria de executa-lo sem ser em *background* abrindo a janela literalmente teria como fazer isso?

Comment: Tipo isso: https://ping.eu/ping/ ?

Comment: isso qualquer comando

Comment: Se sua intenção é executar isso na máquina do cliente, via JS ou PHP é impossível, por questões de segurança. Ou você desenvolve um módulo para rodar na máquina do cliente ou roda em background no seu servidor.

Comment: Se quiser algo rodando na máquina e no browser vais ter que criar um modulo para ser executado na máquina.

Comment: Não sei no windows, mas o mesmo exemplo em um *nix seria: `shell_exec('arquivoaserexecutado &')` O `&` faz com que o processo seja executado em segundo plano, assim o php não ficará preso aguardando retorno mais pois o retorno foi o ID do processo.